# Laravel Auth scaffolding does not render correctly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a new Laravel 5.4 app. I ran `php artisan make:auth` to create the scaffolding. I ran `npm run dev` to compile the CSS/Javascript.

When visiting `/login` the page does not render - it's as if there is just HTML without the CSS.

The error in the browser console is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at app.js:1
```

The `layouts/app.blade.php` file includes `app.js` and `app.css` as expected.

Why isn't it rendering correctly? Have I missed a step in the auth set up?

**Edit: package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^3.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "0.*",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: `php artisan make:auth` is all you need to run to get the auth scaffolding. The application comes default with compiled css and js, you don't need to run npm.

Comment: @Sandeesh Then any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: @Sandeesh I just did a completely fresh installation without running `npm run dev` and I get the same error message.

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using? and can you post the contents of  `package.json` file? Also what i meant was to not run npm command since laravel comes with pre compiled app.js and app.css. These are enough for the auth views to work. As for the error, im looking into it.

Comment: Using 5.4. I've added the package.json. Thank you

Comment: I see no issues with anything. If you're getting errors with a fresh installation then you must have some issues on your end. Try to clear your browser cache and try once.

Comment: Clearing cache does nothing. I'll keep trying. Incidentally the point identified as being the issue in app.css is `$(document).ready(function(){$("*[data-poload]").mouseenter...`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to use jQuery without including the library, but that's just an assumption without seeing the contents of app.js.

Are you including jQuery locally, or via a CDN (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/)? If so, make sure it's imported before app.js.

Comment: I've made literally no changes at all except to run `make:auth`. I will try adding jQuery, but surely it would do that if it was required? I'll give it a go

Comment: I just checked my own Laravel project and make:auth doesn't seem to generate an app.js - at least for me. Try including jQuery and see if that helps.

Comment: No, makes no difference. Same error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at app.js:1`

Comment: @samiles What's line 1 of app.js?

Comment: `/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap`

Comment: @samiles replying here since I don't have a high enough reputation to comment on your original thread. `$(document).ready(***)` is a jQuery call. If that's the line that's throwing the error, are you sure you're including jQuery before app.js is loaded?

Comment: I think it's jQuery too, but others are saying you don't need to add anything and it will just work. But including jQuery makes no difference anyway.